# Chrome Extension Help: Replace URL string on page load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this problem. Specific website, I have visited literally thousands of pages in it. I have enabled css visited links highlighting so I don't waste my time going back to pages I have already seen then ... the website changes its url structure

it used to be: http://www.blah.com/example.phtml?blah&bleh&hit=10&fromsearch
now it became  http://www.blah.com/example.phtml?blah&bleh&hit=10&fromsearch&hit_id=10

which messes up visited pages.

Now the Visited Pages file chrome uses is encrypted so I can't inject "hit_id=10" into all my browsing history and be done with so I am wondering if I can do the reverse with an extension.
Ie strip all instances of "hit_id=10"  from all the links as the page is rendered. I can figure out the js

```
< script type="text/javascript" >
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("&hit_id=10", "g"), "");
< /script >
```

What I can't figure out is how to get to execute (if it can) on all pages it loads from a specific domain

PS yes &hit_id=10 is completely redundant as a field

Any/all help appreciated

Comment: Would it be enough to change `href` property inside `<a>` tags only or you want to replace inside other tags as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would remove it from the links only:

**content_script.js:**

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++){
    el[i].href = el[i].href.replace("&hit_id=10", "");
}
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.blah.com/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```